# Drawing a table

Tags: tables

I want to draw this table, but I don't find the right commands.
Can anyone help me?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  What did you try so far and which specific part of this table is difficult for you?

Comment: While waiting for an answer, you can find some learning material about creating tables at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

Comment: You can use this excellent tool: https://www.latex-tables.com/

Answer (score 5):

I tend to feel that `booktabs`' facilities produce better-looking tables, so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rcp{3cm}c}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn4c{GG\&A Hoofed Stock}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
        Year&\makecell{Price\\low--high}&Comments&Other\\
        \midrule
        1971&97--245&Bad year for farmers in the West.&23,45\\
        72&245--245&Light trading due to a heavy winter.&435,23\\
        73&245--2001&No gnus was very good gnus this year.&387,56\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know how much experience you have with the presentation of tabulated data in LaTeX, so if the above code is utterly arcane to you, you may want to check one of the resources linked in the comments above, or [latexref.xyz](https://latexref.xyz/tabular.html#tabular)'s section on `tabular` environments.

If it's arcane but not *utterly* arcane, then let me point out that `\makecell` is used here for (easily) adding manual linebreaks to cells, that the column specification `p{3cm}` creates a column that's 3 cm wide for the comment field (to keep it from growing too large for long comments; if you'd rather have a fixed number there, you may want to look into the `tabularx` package and its `X` column type), and that `\toprule`,  `\cmidrule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` are rule-drawing commands from `booktabs` --- `\cmidrule` draws a rule spanning specific columns, and `(lr)` indicates that this rule should be trimmed on both sides.

Finally, if you absolutely insist on the same presentation as in your screenshot, then perhaps take a look at the `hhline` package.

(Oh, and lest I forget: since this is sometimes confusing to new users, a `tabular` environment is for presenting data in a table-ish manner, while the `table` environment produces a floating object that is classed as a table (so it'll appear in a `\listoftables`, for instance). A `table` does not have to contain a `tabular`, however, and a `tabular` does not have to be in a `table`.)

Comment: I believe that “Year”, “Price”, ”Comments” and ”Other” should be on the same line, with ”low–high” a line below (it's a caption to the header)

Answer (score 4):

Although I totally agree with chsk's comment about `booktabs`, here is how you could reproduce the table in your question including all the horizontal and vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|r||c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.2cm}|r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{GG\&A Hoofed Stock}\\
\hline
\hline
     & Price     &                                       &        \\
Year & low-high  & Comments                              & Other  \\
\hline
1971 & 97--245   & Bad year for farmers in the West.     & 23,45  \\
\hline
72   & 245--245  & Light trading due to a heavy winter.  & 435,23 \\
\hline
73   & 245--2001 & No gnus was very good gnus this year. & 387,56 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```